# Bounding 2-norm of powers of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, jordan-normal-form, spectral-radius

Suppose that $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with $\rho(A) \leq 1$ and $\|A\|_2 \leq R$, where $R>1$. How can I show an upper bound on $\|A^k\|_2$ that is polynomial in $k$? A trivial upper bound is by the sub-multiplicative property of the norm $ \|A^k\|_2 \leq R^k$, but this bound is exponential in $k$.

---

My attempt:

(1) Suppose that $A$ is symmetric, then $\|A\|_2 = \rho(A)$ and we have $\|A^n\|_2 \leq 1$.

(2) It seems to me that if we show an upper bound on $A$ with all eigenvalues equal to 1, then that bound should work for any $A$ with $\rho(A) \leq 1$. I use a similar method as in the proof of [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Power_sequence). Let $A = P J P^{-1}$ be the Jordan form of $A$ with all eigenvalues equal to 1. Suppose $k > n$. For $A^k = P J^k P^{-1}$ according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Power_sequence), we have

\begin{align}
J^k = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & {k \choose 1} & {k \choose 2} & \dots & {k \choose n-1}\\
0 & 1 & {k \choose 1} & \dots & {k \choose n-2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Then $\|A^k\|_2 \leq \|P\|_2 \|J^k\|_2 \|P^{-1}\|_2 \leq \|P\|_2 \|P^{-1}\|_2 n^2  k^n$, that is polynomial in $k$.
There are a couple of issues with this argument. First, how can I argue that $A$ with all *real* eigenvalues equal to 1 is the worst case? How do I deal with the case of complex eigenvalues with absolute value 1? Second, how can I bound the norms of $\|P\|$ and $\|P^{-1}\|$? Maybe using the information that $\|A\|_2 \leq R$?

Comment: It should hold that $\|A|| \leq ||(|A|)||$, where the absolute value is taken element wise.