# Spectral norm of Jordan basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, jordan-normal-form

Suppose that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $\|A\|_2 \leq R$. and let $A = P J P^{-1}$ be a Jordan canonical form. Are there any upper bounds on the norms $\|P\|_2$ and $\|P^{-1}\|_2$ in terms of $R$ or other quantities related to $A$? If $A$ is symmetric with distinct eigenvalues, then $P$ is the eigenvector matrix and $\|P\|_2, \|P^{-1}\|_2 = 1$. This is related to [the question I asked earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682450/bounding-2-norm-of-powers-of-a-matrix).

Comment: *If $A$ is diagonalizable with distinct eigenvalues, then $P$ is the eigenvector matrix and $\|P\|_2, \|P^{-1}\|_2 = 1$* -- where did you get this?  Consider $P$ being an upper triangular matrix with ones on the diagonal and and every entry above the diagonal being a one. Then  $1 \lt \frac{1}{n}\big \Vert P\big \Vert_F^2  \longrightarrow \big \Vert P\big \Vert_2^2 \gt 1\longrightarrow \big \Vert P\big \Vert_2 \gt 1$

Comment: @user8675309 Good point! For $A$ symmetric with distinct eigenvalues, $P$ is orthonormal and has norm 1.